# Disable option in DropdownButton when selecting an option in another DropdownButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I am creating a mobile app with flutter (using Android Studio). I have the following requirements: I need three Dropdown-Menus (DropdownButton in flutter) with the same list of items. When an item is selected in one of the dropdowns it should get disabled (not able to be selected anymore) in the other two dropdowns.

How can that be done? I am fairly new to flutter but I did something similar once using javascript.

Here's my code so far:

```
List<String> dropDowns = [' -- Wählen Sie ein Fach aus -- ', ' -- Wählen Sie ein Fach aus -- ', ' -- Wählen Sie ein Fach aus -- '];

DropdownButton _createDropDown(var index) {
    var dropdownButton = new DropdownButton<String>(
        value: dropDowns[index],
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
        iconSize: 28,
        elevation: 16,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          fontSize: 22
        ),
        items: <String>[
          ' -- Wählen Sie ein Fach aus -- ',
          'Bildnerisches Gestalten',
          'Deutsch',
          'Französisch',
          'Englisch',
          'Ethik, Religion, Gemeinschaft',
          'Italienisch',
          'Mathematik',
          'Musik',
          'Natur und Technik',
          'Räume, Zeiten, Gesellschaften',
          'Textiles und technisches Gestalten',
          'Wirtschaft, Arbeit, Haushalt'
        ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropDowns[index] = newValue;
          });
        }
    );
    return dropdownButton;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, instead of having a Text widget as a child of the DropdownMenuItem you need to have something that is enabled or disabled according to the current selected DropdownButtons:

```
DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value: value,
  child: CustomText(value, isDisabled: isDisabled(index, value)),
)
```

This would be the widget to show as an option

```
class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final bool isDisabled;

  CustomText(this.text, {this.isDisabled = false});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: isDisabled
                ? Theme.of(context).unselectedWidgetColor
                : Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color),
      ),
      onTap: isDisabled ? () {} : null,
    );
  }
}
```

Note that you need to specify an empty onTap if the option is disabled because otherwise the DropdownMenuItem tap gesture will trigger and select the option

And this would be the condition to know if an option should be disabled

```
bool isDisabled(int index, String value) {
  return dropDowns[index] != value && dropDowns.contains(value);
}
```